# setTimeout VS web worker - when to use what?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout, web-worker, nonblocking

Both setTimeout and web worker more or less do the same thing. They make the main thread non-blocking and does it's work asynchronously in the background.
How do we judge when to use what?

Comment: IMHO they are nowhere close to doing the same thing. `setTimeout()` delays the execution of a code block. `WebWorker` allow to move extensive calculations to a separate thread.

Answer (score 5):

> They make the main thread non-blocking and does it's work asynchronously in the background.

No. They don't. That's what a Web Worker does.

`setTimeout` puts a function on a queue to be run later. When it runs it still runs on the main thread and is just as blocking.

Comment: Okay I get it. But both serve the same purpose right? I can achieve the same goal which I can, through web worker. So, is web worker recommended because it is time independent? And also, why ajax calls don't use web workers instead of setTimeout?

Comment: "why ajax calls don't use web workers instead of setTimeout?" — They typically don't use either!

Comment: "So, is web worker recommended because it is time independent?" — No. Because it does work outside the main thread so it is non-blocking.

Comment: @AyanDalal depends on the implementation. AJAX as a concept, does not mention setTimeout. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: "why ajax calls don't use web workers instead of setTimeout?" — They typically don't use either! - what exactly do they use then?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest or fetch

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest or fetch" - how do they listen to onreadystatechange?

Comment: Their support for asynchronous operations is built-in (and not written in JS).